# Is it possible to integrate the Single sign On between two cakephp sites

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, forms-authentication, forum

How can we use Single Sign-on for the CakePHP Forum and CakePHP website to share the single User authentication.
CakePHP Website shared the domain like ( www.example.com ) and CakePHP forum installed in ( www.forum.example.com ).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest https://github.com/CakeDC/cakephp-forum for the base forum functionality and then implementing the user authentication setup yourself as that is not covered by the plugin. This grants you the flexibility you need for your requirements without having to setup all the boilerplate features i.e. creating threads, categories, comments etc. yourself